# c# crear form1.designer.cs programaticamente

Tags: windows-forms, formularios, diseño-de-clases

Para realizar un formulario se puede:

1. utilizar el diseñador de visual studio,
2. hacerlo programaticamente

yo estoy haciendo ABMF (Alta, Baja, Modificacion, Ficha (CRUD)) de tablas, programaticamente.

He creado una clase donde defino las tablas y sus propiedades, luego con dicha información diseño el formulario, aún tengo pendiente programar para que dicho formulario sea responsivo al usuario.

Para todas las tablas que utilizo en mis programas creo una clase donde las defino y como con dicha informacion creo los formularios ABMF (CRUD) me seria muy util poder generar los designer y utilizarlos.

Quisiera que cuando estoy visualizando estos formularios (o cualquier otro) y estoy ejecutando el programa, grabar el form1.designer.cs que corresponde al formulario que estoy visualizando.

No quiero modificar el código fuente de mi programa.

El formulario que estoy visualizando fue generado por programación, pero aun no he terminado de desarrollarlo (que funcione total y correctamente).

Entonces momentaneamente quisiera poder generar el Form1.designer.cs para utilizarlo mientras termino de desarrollar las funcionalidades automaticas.

He investigado y encontré como guardar el formulario en visual studio, pero no como hacerlo desde el mismo programa mientras se esta ejecutando.

En cuanto a que he intentado, he googleado y todo lo que he encontrado es como guardar el formulario luego de diseñarlo o guardar una solución.

Tambien he consultado IA pero como siempre sus respuestas son erroneas y pide disculpas y ofrece otras posibles respuestas.

No he encontrado como guardar el diseño del form mientras se ejecuta el programa.

Una forma seria generar linea a linea el form1.designer.cs, pero si visual studio lo genera y lo guarda, deberia existir una forma de hacerlo automaticamente.

Parece que la solucion seria experimentar con las API CodeDom o Roslyn para generar código dinamico.

Talvez alguien con mas conocimiento en estas API pueda ayudarme o guiarme.

Comment: Buenas dias Hugo, tu pregunta como esta redactada actualemnte no se entiende. Porque al ejecutar un programa debería modificarse su código fuente? Que es lo que tratas de hacer realmente y que has intentado? Saludos

Comment: no intento cambiar su codigo fuente, quiero generar un archivo de diseño que corresponda con el formulario que se genero programaticamente